# WP_Query not returning custom post type

Tags: wp-query

I'm using the below code to try to return the count of custom post types but the query isn't finding anything. I change the post_type to project and it works fine. This is also being used outside of the loop if that makes a difference?

```
 function get_user_posts_count($user_id, $post_type) {
    $args['author']     = 1;
    $args['post_type']  = 'project';
    $args['posts_per_page'] = -1;
    $args['post_status']    = 'any, trash';

    $ps = new WP_Query( $args );

    echo var_dump ($ps);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`WP_Query` does not accept a comma delimited string for the `post_type` argument, it must be one of either a `string` (for one `post_type`) or an `array` (for one-or-more `post_type`).

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

OR

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 
    array(
        'post'
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

OR

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 
    array(
        'post',
        'page',
        'movie',
        'book'
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Useful reading:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-type-parameters